# How to sync data between databases (each database for each instance of a service) in Microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, microservices, distributed-computing, database-partitioning

If each instance of service has a separate database in Microservices architecture, how can we keep the data synced? For instance, if instace#1 serves a request and stores data in its database db#1 and another request on instannce#2 wants the data that was inserted to db#1 through instance#1, how can the database db#2 of instance#2 get the data from the database db#1 of instance#2? I think z-scaling is the solution here!

Comment: A separate database schema per microservice is a best-practice. But every instance of a microservice should not have its own database.

Answer (score 3):

The microservice architecture uses a pattern called 'Eventual consistency'. Like you described, newly inserted data won't be directly available in all databases. You can read more about it [here](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-trade-offs.html)

That being said, the CQRS pattern is a populair way to solve the data distrubution / eventual consistency problem.
[image]

By using a messagebroker / bus, you can publish so called 'events' on a queue.
Microservices interested in changes / certain entities, can subscribe to those entities and save them in their own database.
This enables loosely coupled microservices, and the data necessary for certain entities is stored in the same database. Data duplication is ok, since we use eventual cosistency to make sure (eventually) everything is in sync over all microservices.

More information about the CQRS pattern using microservices can be found [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/cqrs.html)

Here's a more practical example of something i'm working on right now. The language is in Dutch, but the flow should be self explanatory:
[image]

Hope this helps!
I suggest reading up on the following topics: CQRS, microservices, eventual consistency and messagebrokers (rabbitmq, kafka, etc)

Comment: I think the Question is related to Single Service having two instances running separate DB instances. Ideally It should not be the architecture design. But even you want to create DB per instance then look for DB sync tool.

Comment: If that's the case CQRS would still be applicable, since you'd still be using a messagebroker to share created entities

Comment: I thought CQRS is used to query the data from multiple services and SAGA patterns is used to maintain the data consistency across services.

Comment: I think you switched those two terms up

Comment: My question is around data sync between databases of each instance of the SAME service. I agree that ideally, we should be having a database/service rather than database/instance but in a special case if there is a database/instance, how would we do sync the data between databases of each instance instantly?

Comment: Lke I said, you could apply the same principle.
One service could publish a message (event) on the messagebroker, e.g: CreatedEntityEvent. 
The other service instance should listen (subscribe) to those events.
Therefore, if one service instance inserts (creates) an entity, publishes it to the messagebroker, the other service instance would be able to subscribe to that entity and save it in its own database.

I think I have provided enough material, you should try to read some of them

Comment: @JavaYouth I know this thread is a little old, but we are working on a company called Redactics (https://www.redactics.com) where one of our service offerings is delta database syncs running in a managed workflow you run in your own infrastructure. I'll spare you the sales talk, but if you are still looking for a solution here this might fit the bill. Please drop us a line!